# Add Color to classes in scatterplot matrix (pairs)

Tags: categorical-data

I have my class defined in "unscaled.BL_yFYield_CSUSHPINSA" (basically, 1:up 0:down).  I wish to color the scatterplot into classes akin to how this example demonstrates species are supposedly highlighted by 3 colors (note, I've reduced my example to two colors).

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/scatter-plot-matrices-r-base-graphs

this [image](http://www.sthda.com/sthda/RDoc/figure/graphs/scatterplot-matrices-color-by-groups-1.png) specifically is what I'm trying to achieve (coloring based on my_cols and a categorical variable).  In the iris example, I only saw two species (when I iterated iris$species), but the online code uses 3 colors in the graph, so I'm not sure how that works data.

My example I have two colors for two classes (however, eventually I wish to extend my number of classes beyond 2).

Example, assuming BL_yFYield_CSUSHPINSA had the following values for categorical 0, 1, 2 and I had 3 colors defined in my_cols.

Right now when I graph the output, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4I7B.jpg) is what I get

```
pre_MyData <- read.csv(file="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thistleknot/FredAPIR/master/reduced.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

MyData <- pre_MyData[,11:18]

my_cols <- c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800") 
pairs(MyData[,1:8], pch = 19, cex = 0.5,
      col = my_cols[MyData$unscaled.BL_yFYield_CSUSHPINSA],
      lower.panel = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought about it.  The answer was in my screenshot.  my_cols is skipping values with 0 in BL_yfield... (treating it as null).  I could try to fix it after the fax, or I could add 1 to my original dataset to remove 0's...

problem [solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgk6U.jpg)

```
pre_MyData <- read.csv(file="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thistleknot/FredAPIR/master/reduced.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

MyData <- pre_MyData[,11:18]

my_cols <- c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800") 
pairs(MyData[,1:8], pch = 19, cex = 0.5,
      col = my_cols[MyData$unscaled.BL_yFYield_CSUSHPINSA+1],
      lower.panel = NULL)
```